# A query that return a table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Could someone please help with a query that would return a table of all latest JOHN updates.

```
From LeadManagement$StatusLog
Get createdDate, StatusFrom, StatusTo
WHERE MandyOrJOHNStatus = 'JOHN'
And the createdDate is between the date range you want to look at.
Order by createDate Descending and Distinct by JOHNAppID (below)
Join with LeadManagement$StatusLog_Lead to LeadManagement$Lead
To Get LeadNumber, JOHNAppID and JOHNBrandAppID
```

Comment: No idea what that is, but at least it's not SQL...

Comment: It is not clear what is your **specific problem**. Please read [ask] in [help] for more info how to use and how to ask in StackOverflow!

Comment: As well you have tagged this as both MySQL and various versions of SQL Server. Which of the two are you using? They are very different in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly know what you are looking for here... but I believe the following query might help you

```
SELECT LMS.createdDate,
       LMS.StatusFrom,
       LMS.StatusTo,
       LMSS_L.LeadNumber,
       DISTINCT (LMSS_L.JOHNAppID) ,JOHNBrandAppID
FROM   LeadManagement$StatusLog LMS
JOIN   LeadManagement$Lead LML ON *common column in both* 
JOIN   LeadManagement$StatusLog_Lead LMSS_L ON *common column in both*  
WHERE  MandyOrJOHNStatus = 'JOHN'
  AND  createdDate BETWEEN *the date range you want to look at*
ORDER BY createDate DESC
```

This solution is only to the best of my knowledge, hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think you can do `column_name AND column_name2` in SQL Server as you do right before the `FROM`. I'm wondering whether `LMSS_L.eadNumber` should be `LMSS_L.LeadNumber`. And finally I would advise you not to use `BETWEEN` for `DATETIME` columns as explained in this [this blog-post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: Yes @funkwurm, 'AND' cannot be used that way, Since I was copy pasting the code given in the question, I must've missed the AND. Have corrected it now.

Comment: Shivangi its working perfectly SELECT createdDate, StatusFrom, StatusTo , leadnumber,JOHNAppID,JOHNBrandAppID,MandyOrJOHNStatus
FROM  LeadManagement$StatusLog as LMS  WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN LeadManagement$StatusLog_Lead LMS_L WITH (NOLOCK)
ON LMS_L.leadmanagement$statuslogid = LMS.id
INNER JOIN LeadManagement$Lead LML WITH (NOLOCK)
ON LML.id = LMS_L.leadmanagement$leadid
WHERE MandyOrJOHNStatus = 'JOHN'
  AND  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),lms.createdDate,121) between '2015-03-09' and '2015-03-13'
ORDER BY LMS.createddate DESC